# I want to send an email with attachment using Azure pipeline task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I have created test pipeline in Azure release pipeline. Test report gets generated on VM/agent machine after execution. Can i use any task that will help me to send this report to few team members?

Answer (score 0):

We're using this extension, which has option to add an attachment

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask

Comment: This task has option for attachment. can you please suggest me way if i can attach multiple files in same email?

Comment: Hi @Suraj Shinde I tried to attach multiple files, the task failed to recognize the path I entered. You can add a `copy files task` to copy all the attachments to a place and then use `archive files task` to make a zip file of your attachments. Then you can attach the zip file to the email task.